# How to sort multiple columns data in Multi-Dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, columnsorting

I am working with a JavaScript code where I have an array like below:

**Array:**

```
[
    ["2015-08-09", 1.2, 1.20, 2.1],
    ["2015-08-10", 1.2, 1.21, 2.11],
    ["2015-08-11", 1.2, 0.99, 2.20],
    ["2015-10-29", 1.2, 1.12, 2.22],
    ["2015-09-10", 1.21, 1.19, 2.00]
]
```

**My required Result is:**

```
[
    ["2015-08-09", 1.20, 1.20, 2.10],
    ["2015-08-10", 1.20, 1.21, 2.11],
    ["2015-08-11", 1.20, 0.99, 2.20],
    ["2015-10-29", 1.20, 1.12, 2.22],
    ["2015-09-10", 1.21, 1.19, 2.00]
]
```

As the array is 3 dimensional I want to sort on `column 1` and `2`, so first apply ascending on column `1` and then column `2` (Ascending/descending).

Comment: Isn't it two-dimensional? Just saying'

Comment: No its more than 2 dimensional array, and its dynamic array?

Comment: About the array being dynamic...we can't help you if you don't give us more info about what it means to be dynamic and maybe an example.

Comment: After you updated the original question, the input array and the expected result are actually the same thing, can you improve this or give more feedback to what you really need now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also face the same issue and found a good solution for sort multiple columns data in Multi-Dimensional array.

Check the below code

```js
(function() {
      function deepsort(){
    var i, order= arguments, L= order.length, tem;
    return a.sort(function(a, b){
        i= 0;
      
        while(i < L){
          
            tem= order[i++];
          var res = tem.split("_");
            var ao= a[res[0]] || 0, bo= b[res[0]] || 0;
            if(ao== bo) continue;
           
          if(res[1] == "ASC"){
            return ao > bo? 1: -1;
          }
          if(res[1] == "DESC"){
             return ao < bo? 1: -1;
          }
        }
        return 0;
    });
}

var a= [
    ["2015-08-09", 1.2, 1.20, 2.1],
    ["2015-08-10", 1.2, 1.21, 2.11],
    ["2015-08-11", 1.2, 0.99, 2.20],
    ["2015-10-29", 1.2, 1.12, 2.22],
    ["2015-09-10", 1.21, 1.19, 2.00]
];
document.write(deepsort(1+"_ASC",2+"_ASC"));
// for better result view check console log
console.log(deepsort(1+"_ASC",2+"_ASC"))
//console.log(a.deepsort(1))
    
    })();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just chain the wanted order by taking the delta of each column.

```js
var array = [["2015-08-09", 1.2, 1.2], ["2015-08-10", 1.2, 1.21], ["2015-08-11", 1.2, 0.99], ["2015-10-29", 1.2, 1.12], ["2015-09-10", 1.21, 1.19]];

array.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1] || a[2] - b[2]);

console.log(array.map(a => a.join('  ')));
```

Comment: The fact that you understood that `column 1 and 2` are really the columns indexed with 1 and 2 amazes me, hehe. Not a lot of people use 0-index-based system when speaking.

Comment: Array dimensions are dynamic and it can increase. So currently looking 2 dimensional can increase to n dimension. and sort is also going to increase on multiple columns.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have another approach using a more like mathematical expression on the sort comparison function, and also formats the output as you expected:

```js
const input = [
    ["2015-08-09", 1.2, 1.20, 2.1],
    ["2015-08-10", 1.2, 1.21, 2.11],
    ["2015-08-11", 1.2, 0.99, 2.20],
    ["2015-10-29", 1.2, 1.12, 2.22],
    ["2015-09-10", 1.21, 1.19, 2.00]
];

// First, we use map() to clone the array so we don't change
// the original, and also to format the numbers as you expect.

let res = input.map(
  ([a, b, c, d]) => [a, b.toFixed(2), c.toFixed(2), d.toFixed(2)]
);

// Now we sort the new array using a more-like mathematical expression.

res.sort((x, y) =>
{
    let n = x[1] - y[1], m = x[2] - y[2];
    return n +  m * (n === 0);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually your array is 2-dimensional. You can sort it the same way as 1-dimensional array:

```js
const data = [
  [ "2015-08-09", 1.2, 1.2], 
  [ "2015-08-10", 1.2, 1.21], 
  [ "2015-08-11", 1.2, 0.99],
  [ "2015-10-29",  1.2, 1.12] , 
  [ "2015-09-10",  1.21, 1.19]   
]

function sort(a, b) {
  const col1 = new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]);
  if (col1 === 0) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
  }
  return col1;
}

console.log(data.sort(sort))
```

In above example we sort first by the first field in inner array. If values are equal - then we compare the second field of inner array.

Comment: Except the fact that this does not return the desired result by OP (even if I implemented it the same way).